# python packages are not supported for my current wheel version

Tags: python

I was trying to install some packages but it gives me an error saying that my whl version is not supported

my commands -

```
!pip3 install folium==0.2.1
!pip3 install --upgrade pip==20.0.2 setuptools==46.1.3
!pip3 install --upgrade --force-reinstall -e .
```

[image]

Comment: Please don't post error messages as screenshots; copy and paste them (and format them as code blocks) instead. Screenshots are hard to read for some people, and impossible to search.